# Cart value sent in mail

Tags: php, email

I am writing a custom mailer form in which I want to send the cart value details along with contact details.

I tried like this:

```
$product_name = explode(', ', $_REQUEST['product_name'], 2);
$numbers = [];
foreach ($product_name as $key => $value) {
    $numbers[] = $value . " ,";
}
$pr_name = implode(',', $numbers);
// foreach($product_name as $value) {
//     $qtyOut = $value."<br>";
// }
// $pname = $qtyOut;
$product_qty = explode(', ', $_REQUEST['product_qty'], 2);
$qty = [];
foreach ($product_qty as $key => $value) {
    $qty[] = $value . " ,";
}
$pr_qty = implode('', $qty);
echo $pr_name;
echo $pr_qty;   

$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Product Name:</strong> </td><td>$pr_name</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Product Quantity:</strong> </td><td>$pr_qty</td></tr>";
```

When I am sending data, only last row value is sent, not other details. May be I think... there is a problem in array or foreach loop. Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure `$_REQUEST['product_name']` and `$_REQUEST['product_qty']` have more than 1 element and that they are indeed separated by `, `?

Comment: yes... that is 4 element

Comment: And I'm guessing you want the first 2 values from both, right? Note that  since you specified the array limit as 2 in `explode(', ', $_REQUEST['product_name'], 2);`, the first element of the array will be fine, but the second element will contain the remaining string (i.e. elements 2, 3, and 4) as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: yes, thats ok... but i have 4 row, and i am getting only one row. how will i get all four row?

Comment: I ran your code by setting `$_REQUEST['product_name']` to `"A, B, C, D"` and `$_REQUEST['product_qty']` to `"2, 4, 6, 3"`. I get the following output `A ,,B, C, D ,2 ,4, 6, 3 ,`, which is as expected. So I don't see anything wrong with your code unless those two request variables don't have data in the expected format. You can post the values of those 2 variables; that'll make it easier to help you.

Comment: If you want to print each row separately, then you don't need to `implode`; you can simply loop through `$product_name` and `$product_qty`, each time printing the array items.